# Parsing recursive templates with pyparsing

Tags: python, regex, pyparsing

I'm currently trying to parse recursive templates with pyparsing. A template can look like this:

```
{{Attribute
| name=attr1
| description=First attribute.}}
```

The template has a name (Attribute) and defines some variables (name = attr1, description = First attribute.). However, there are also templates which can contain zero or more templates:

```
{{Enum
| name=MyEnum
| description=Just a test enum.
| example=Not given...
| attributes={{Attribute
| name=attr1
| description=First attribute.}}
{{Attribute
| name=attr2
| description=Second attribute.}}}}
```

To parse these templates I came up with the following:

```
template = Forward()
lb = '{{'
rb = '}}'
template_name = Word(alphas)
variable = Word(alphas)
value = CharsNotIn('|{}=') | Group(ZeroOrMore(template))
member = Group(Suppress('|') + variable + Suppress('=') + value)
members = Group(OneOrMore(member))
template << Suppress(lb) + Group(template_name + members) + Suppress(rb)
```

This works quite well, but it does not allow me to use "|{}=" within a value which is problematic if I want to use them. E.g.:

```
{{Enum
| name=MyEnum
| description=Just a test enum.
| example=<python>x = 1</python>
| attributes=}}
```

So, how can I change my code so that it allows these characters, too? Unforunately, I have no idea how I can archieve this.

I hope someone can give me some tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for: https://github.com/earwig/mwparserfromhell